# linked list change when i change the array of character

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, linked-list

The problem is when the second time i put a any word the q->ch in the if statement change to the new word
   .. I want q become the pointer of the start of the linked list

```
while(true){
    tmp=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    printf("\n put any word:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\n");
    tmp->ch=name;
        if (i==0)
    {
        q=p=tmp;

    }
    else
    {
        p->nxt=tmp;
        p=tmp;
    }

    printf("when you want to end press y \n");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    if (c=='Y' || c=='y')
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the address of `name` to `tmp->ch`. The content of the address of `name` is always overwritten by `scanf()`. Strings and character arrays can't be copied with `=` sign. You need to use `strcpy()` and family to copy a string from one array to another. However, if you dynamically allocate memory for `name` and define `ch` as `char *` then your solution will work.

Comment: It looks like you've only got one array for the string, and you keep overwriting it.  Allocate a new `name` each time.

Comment: please do not use tabs when indenting code, always use spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q` does point to the first node in the list. The problem is that when you do

```
tmp->ch = name
```

you are only copying an address. So, every node gets to point to the same bufer which will end with the last word.

To fix it, a copy of the string needs to be done:

```
tmp->ch = strdup (name)
```

Comment: in the end, remember to free all those 'dup' strings, so no memory leak is created.